# Angular For submit twice to see data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a mini-project to brush up on my Angular but it seems I forgot more than I thought. I'm using 2 components *weather-search* and *display-weather* and they communicate through the *HomeController*. Now, what happens is this, when I enter a value (either city or zip) and submit the form, the console will log the return with the JSON data from the API, but it won't display in the UI **unless** the form is re-submitted then it will update with the search result, essentially, every second submit will update the UI. Why? :(

**app.js**

```
var angular = require('angular')

angular.module(`weather_app`, [])
  .controller('HomeController', function(){
    this.data = ''
  })
require('./services/index')
require('./components/weather-search')
require('./components/display-weather')
```

**weather-search.js**

```
angular.module('weather_app')
  .component('weatherSearch', {
    templateUrl: './templates/weather.html',
    bindings: {
      weather: '&'
    },
    controller: WeatherSearchController
  })

function WeatherSearchController(WeatherService, CountryService){
    var ctrl = this
    ctrl.title = "Weather App!"

    ctrl.searchWeather = function(data) {
      // ...
      WeatherService.getCurrent(data.option, data.value)
        .then( result => {
          // ...
          ctrl.weather({$event: {data: result}})
        })
        .catch( error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    }
}
```

**display-weather.js**

```
angular.module('weather_app')
  .component('displayWeather', {
    template:`
      Display: {{ $ctrl.weather }}
    `,
    bindings: {
      weather: '<'
    }
  })
```

**weather.pug**

```
div(class="weather")
  h1.
    {{ ::$ctrl.title }}

  div(class="weather-search")
    form
      select(ng-init="weather.option = weather.option || 'zip'", ng-model="weather.option")
        option(value="zip").
          Zip Code
        option(value="city").
          City
      input(class="weather-search-input", ng-model="weather.value")
      select(ng-init="weather.type = weather.type || 'f'", ng-model="weather.type")
        option(value="f").
          Fahrenheit
        option(value="c").
          Celsius
        option(value="k").
          Kelvin
      button(type="submit", ng-click="$ctrl.searchWeather(weather)").
        Search
  div(ng-if="$ctrl.error", class="error").
    {{ $ctrl.error }}
```

Comment: too much code bro, I can't understand you problem

Comment: weather.pug is inside a form tag? Can you show us that code?

Comment: @NadeemKhoury I feared as much. Let me see if I can sum it up better. What's happening is, the event for the binding from the weather-search to display-weather is only happening when another event is registered. So, I enter the zipcode, press Search, nothing happens. I either delete the input value, press a button, a dropdown, then the information appears.